# Can I prevent push on a local repository?

Tags: svn, mercurial

Currently my setup is this :

> External SVN repository --> local svn
>   working copy, transformed in a
>   mercurial repository --> clone of this
>   repository as subrepo in my
>   application repo

The external SVN is a library which I don't have any privilege on.

Basically, I want to prevent pushing changes to my svn/hg hybrid repository, so the changes come only from the library's svn repository.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) in mercurial. For example in svnhgrepository/.hg/hgrc file, the following section will cause push from another repo to fail (using the [prechangegroup](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:prechangegroup) hook).

```
[hooks]
prechangegroup = false
```

Comment: Oh. I didn't know you could do that with hooks! Thanks!